# background: url (); no muestra imagenes locales en carpetas dentro del index

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, imagen

Tengo un problema y es que al utilizar background: url(imagen.jpg); no muestra ninguna imagen en la pagina.

Solo me ha servido con url de imagenes ya en internet por ejemplo:
https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/09/15/14/22/coast-4478424__340.jpg

En cambio yo quiero utilizar mis imagenes descargadas y ya comporbe los directorios y no funciona, ejemplo:
url(images/oso.jpg);

```css
.img-idea2 {
  background: url(https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/team-idea-collaboration-35712050.jpg);
  width: 90%;
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 100vh;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-idea2">
  <div class="bg-txt-img">
    <h2 class="txt-img-middle3">publish my idea in meet community to have my team</h2>
    <h4 style="color: rgb(219, 219, 219);" class="txt-img-middle4">
      <a href="#">
        <strong class="btn btn-light2">post</strong></a>
    </h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: En donde esta el texto deberia mostrar la imagen]

Comment: Hola, duda tal vez muy obvia, ¿si pones la URL entre comillas?

Comment: Realize eso pero tampoco se soluciona, tengo un banner igual con background: url(images/banner.jpg); y funciona bien sin poner comillas pero al realizar eso mismo en las otras clases no funciona

Comment: Considero que ayudaría mas rapido a encontrar el error que verifiques la ruta de tus imágenes, tal vez estas escribiendo mal la ruta, puedes por ejemplo escribir de nuevo la llamada a una imagen local, abrir el navegador y acceder con f12 a las herramientas de desarrollador para verificar si te arroja por ejemplo un 404

Comment: Gracias, me sirvio en algo, el error estaba en que yo creia que debia especificar el directorioi empezando desde el index pero empieza en donde esta el archivo .css entonces debia retroceder dos directorios y despues ir a la carpeta de la s imagenes y ya seleccionar la imagen.

Comment: MUCHAS GRACIAS :)

Answer (score 1):

En mi caso fue poner la ruta de mi imagen en **comillas simples**

*Ejemplo antes*

```
.ejemplo{
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background: url(/imagenes/cubo-stickerless.jpg)
    margin-bottom:40px;
}
```

*Ejemplo después*

```
.ejemplo{
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background: url('/imagenes/cubo-stickerless.jpg')
    margin-bottom:40px;
}
```